# The meaning of a sentence in Dracula

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"I saw the Count lying within the box upon the earth, some of which the rude falling from the cart had scattered over him." Would anyone tell me the meaning? thanks in advance.

Comment: This question might be better on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The Count was lying on top of dirt that was within the box. Then the box fell off the cart. The fall caused some of the dirt that was in the bottom of the box to get scattered over the Count. (That is, the Count was sleeping in the box, and was lying on top of a layer of dirt that covered the inside bottom of the box.) imo. -- Hopefully my memory isn't failing me here.

Comment: This question could be improved by indicating exactly which part of the sentence is troubling. Is it *the rude falling* perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

"In an instant [Jonathan] had jumped upon the cart, and, with a strength which seemed incredible, raised the great box, and flung it over the wheel to the ground..."

After the box (coffin) was opened, "I saw the Count lying within the box upon the earth, some of which the rude falling from the cart had scattered over him."

So, yes, *rude falling* basically means *violent drop.* The coffin/box suffered a violent drop (rude falling) to the ground. That fall or drop kicked up some of the dirt (earth) inside the coffin and scattered it upon the Count.